# How can I send an email based on yesterday's date in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script in google sheets which checks my sheet to see if it has been updated and then send an email if it hasn't. Basically, to scan the last row for yesterday's date and if it returns that date, send email.

None of the scripts I've come up with so far have worked. Is there a simple script that simply does something like: scan last row, if date in C3 is yesterday, send email?

{EDIT} Thank you for your replies.

I have now added a column which reads either "Yes" or "No" depending on whether or not the date in another column is today or in the past. I've adapted the following script:

```
   function Checkcell() {
  // Fetch the cell data
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Erith").getRange("AD2:AD"); 
  var answer = range.getValue();
if (answer ="Yes"){
     // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Erith').getRange('AD2:B');
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail("email", "MIS Information", "Please complete MIS information using the google doc"); 
}
}
```

This seems to work but how can I get it to read the last row only of my sheet instead of all the rows?

Comment: Please provide your efforts so far and the script you have with the xact problem description. Also provide a sample sheet that visualizes what your dates look like and how they are formatted.

Comment: Thank you Marios, that's a great help! I appreciate your efforts and thank you for explaining what you've done with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your question:

```
function Checkcell(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Erith")  
//var cell_row = 3
var cell_row = sheet.getLastRow() // this will give you the last row of your sheet with content
var cell_check =  sheet.getRange(cell_row,3).getValue() // assuming the "Yes" is in column C
Logger.log(cell_check)

if (cell_check == "Yes") 
{  
var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(cell_row,2).getValue() // assuming the email is in column B
var message = 'This is the message/body of the email'; // Second column
var subject = 'This is the subject of the email';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject , message); // subject 
}
}
```

I had to make a lot of changes to the code you provided. First of all, I added the line:

```
var cell_row = sheet.getLastRow()
```

which gets the last column that contains data. Be careful as this can be any column. For example, if the last value in column A is in cell A10 and the last value in column B is B5, then this line will give you 10, since 10 is the last row that has content.

I also made the following assumptions:

1. Column B has the email address,
2. Column C has the "Yes" or "No" depending on the date,
3. Email address and "Yes" or "No" belong to the same row (for example B3, C3)

If you don't want to consider the last row, you can also specify the row by yourself. Comment out the line:

```
var cell_row = 3
```

and comment the one that uses getLastRow().